# UIView: cannot add multiple CALayer, only the root one appears

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, calayer

I am trying to add some sublayers to the root view layer. The idea is to mix a yellow and a red shadow for the view.

I tried this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var testView: UIView! {
        didSet {
            testView.backgroundColor = .white
            testView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        
        testView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        testView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        testView.layer.shadowRadius = 24.0
        
        let layer1 = CALayer()
        layer1.frame = testView.bounds
        layer1.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer1.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        layer1.shadowRadius = 24.0
        testView.layer.addSublayer(layer1)
    }
}
```

But only the root layer appears (the yellow one), not the red sublayer:

[image]

Why is this happening? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues...

1. For a layer to have a shadow, it must have a background color.
2. `testView` may not be its final size in `viewDidLoad()` ... You should add the layer either *after* `viewDidLoad`, or subclass `UIView` and set the layer's frame in `layoutSubviews`

Give this a quick try:

```
class SubLayerShadowViewController: UIViewController {

    let testView = UIView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(testView)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
            testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.widthAnchor),
            testView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            testView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        testView.backgroundColor = .white
        testView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        
        testView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        testView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        testView.layer.shadowRadius = 24.0

        // move this out of viewDidLoad()
        //let layer1 = CALayer()
        //layer1.cornerRadius = 10.0
        //layer1.frame = testView.bounds
        //layer1.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        //layer1.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        //layer1.shadowRadius = 24.0
        //testView.layer.addSublayer(layer1)

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        let layer1 = CALayer()
        layer1.cornerRadius = 10.0
        layer1.frame = testView.bounds
        layer1.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer1.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        layer1.shadowRadius = 24.0
        
        // set this layer's backgroundColor to the view's backgroundColor
        layer1.backgroundColor = testView.backgroundColor?.cgColor

        testView.layer.addSublayer(layer1)

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about the `backgroundColor`. To make it more convenient, I created a `UIView` subview and moved the related code into `layoutSubviews()`, it works perfectly fine. Thanks again!

Comment: @AnotherDude - yep... once you think about it -- If the layer is empty there's nothing there to "cast a shadow" -- it makes perfect sense :)